# Outputting JSON data in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to make a website that displays data from an URL in JSON format. I tried

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON('https://some-url.com', function(data) {
                    document.write(data.attribute);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </h1>
    <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
</div>
```

but that replaces the whole site instead of simply replacing the text within the h1 tags.

Currently, I'm trying to use

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 id="replace-this"> text </h1>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON('https://some-url.com', function(data) {
                    var thing = data.attribute;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(thing);
                });
            });
        </script>
    <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
</div>
```

but that keeps the text and doesn't output the JSON data.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.  Replace the text of the element instead.  And, don't set the HTML either... set the text.

Comment: Your first example is thoroughly invalid HTML. You cannot place a script inside a `<h1>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fully functional example, your second example it's fine, you just need to change `demo` with `replace-this`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 id="replace-this"> text </h1>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(data) {
        var thing = data; // in your case it's data.attribute
        document.getElementById("replace-this").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(thing, null, 4);
      });
    });
  </script>
  <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the additional parameters for stringify after thing?

Comment: This is the sytnax: `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])`, you can read the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)